# ignorePaths and ignoreActions not working inside getDefaultMiddleware in Redux (Non-serializable value error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was getting a non-serializable value error while using Redux `serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:234 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:`. I tried following https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data documentation and disable serializable check for specific items. However, it did not work.

I have a CustomSlice slice as follows:

```
interface CustomItem {
  dateTime: Dayjs
  .....
}
export interface SomeState {
  customVals: Array<CustomItem>; 
 ....
}

const initialState: SomeState = {
  customVals: new Array<CustomItem>, 
  ...
};
export const customsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'customs',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
  updateCustoms: (state, action) => {
  //using the date value here by individually extracting from customVals
  },
});
```

I tried configuring the store to ignore using non-serialization check for updateCustoms but I still get the same error:

```
import customReducer from './CustomSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      customs: customReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            // Ignore these action types
            ignoredPaths: ['customs.customVals'], //also tried ['customs']
            // Also tried ignoredActions: ['customs/updateCustoms']
          },
        }),
});
```

I am OK to ignore this entire slice but not sure how to do.

Comment: As a first suggestion: can you switch from storing actual `Date` or `Dayjs` instances to storing the dates as strings or numbers instead?  FWIW, the store setup _looks_ like it should be working.

Comment: Sadly, I HAVE to use **Dayjs** instance because  that is how internal tool operates and changing the type will break the feature. Providing exception to this particular slice was my only hope else I might have to do **serializable:false** as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include both ignoredPaths and ignoredActions, to disable serializableCheck on the specific store entry, as it didn't work with either of them on their own.

In your case it should be:

```
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredPaths: ['customs.customVals'],
        ignoredActions: ['customs/updateCustoms']
      },
```

serializableCheck is checking for both store values and actions.